# Installing software for server only on terminal server

Tags: terminal-server, windows-terminal-services

I'm in the process of developing software for a Windows based RDP
terminal server consisting of a server.exe for the server and a client.exe for all terminal server users.

I've created an MSI for each. I've installed the server.msi under execute mode and the client.msi under install mode.

After acquiring a client session via RDP, I can see the server.exe has been started for this client session as well as running on the server.

How do I just install the server.msi to install it's files to run on the server only?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This question makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Did you develop your server.exe as an actual [Windows Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service)? Or is it just an executable that expects to be run in an interactive console session?

If it's the latter, you're "doing it wrong" as they say.  If it's the former, then you've likely done something wrong with your installer. Either way, this is probably a better question for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: It is a C++ executable which is started by a Windows Service.  Based on your answer I've now installed the server.msi as a 'per user' installation which currently looks like the solution.  Thanks.